# Nginx Ingress Controller getting error in Node.js application with routes prefixed

Tags: node.js, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, nginx-ingress

I'm using Ingress Nginx Controller in my Kubernetes Cluster hosted on Google Kubernetes Engine. The application is a Node.js app.

When I integrated my app with [Rollbar](https://rollbar.com/) (logger service) I started to notice repetitive errors every ~15 seconds (154K times in one week).

```
Error: Cannot GET /
```

Print:

[image: Error on Rollbar]

[image: Error details]

I think the reason is the fact that the my Node.js application uses the `/v1` prefix in the routes, i.e the `/` route doesn'i exists.

PS: Rollbar is linked in Develop (local), Testing (Heroku) and Production (GKE) environments and the error only occurs in production.

My ingress file:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: ingress-app
spec:
    rules:
        - host: api.company.com
          http:
              paths:
                  - path: /v1
                    backend:
                        serviceName: company-prod-v1-service
                        servicePort: 3000
```

Ingress documentation [says something about `/` endpoint](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/), but i don't understand very well.

I need to remove this error. Can any jedi masters help me fix this error?

Thanks in advance

[UPDATE]

Deployment File

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: app-deploy-v1
    labels:
        app: app-v1
        version: 1.10.0-2
spec:
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: app-v1
    replicas: 1
    strategy:
        type: RollingUpdate
        rollingUpdate:
            maxUnavailable: 1
    minReadySeconds: 30
    progressDeadlineSeconds: 60
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: app-v1
                version: 1.10.0-2
        spec:
            serviceAccountName: gke-account
            containers:
                - name: app-container
                  image: registry.gitlab.com/company/app-back:1.10.0
                  lifecycle:
                      postStart:
                          exec:
                              command:
                                  - "/bin/sh"
                                  - "-c"
                                  - >
                                      if [ -f "$SECRETS_FOLDER/$APPLE_NOTIFICATION_KEY" ]; then
                                          cp $SECRETS_FOLDER/$APPLE_NOTIFICATION_KEY $APP_FOLDER;
                                      fi;
                - name: cloud-sql-proxy
                  image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.17
                  command:
                      - "/cloud_sql_proxy"
                      - "-instances=thermal-petal-283313:us-east1:app-instance=tcp:5432"
                  securityContext:
                      runAsNonRoot: true
                  lifecycle:
                      preStop:
                          exec:
                              command: ["/bin/sleep", "300"]
            imagePullSecrets:
                - name: registry-credentials
```

Ingress Controller Pod File (auto generate in installation command)

```yaml
 apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-06-16T03:08:53Z"
  generateName: ingress-nginx-controller
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
  name: ingress-nginx-controller
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: ingress-nginx-controller
  resourceVersion: "112544950"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/ingress-nginx/pods/ingress-nginx-controller
spec:
  containers:
    image: k8s.gcr.io/ingress-nginx/controller:v0.46.0
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command:
          - /wait-shutdown
    livenessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 5
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 10254
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
    name: controller
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      name: http
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 443
      name: https
      protocol: TCP
    - containerPort: 8443
      name: webhook
      protocol: TCP
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: /healthz
        port: 10254
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 10
      periodSeconds: 10
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
```

Comment: The frequency of the error makes me think about a liveness probe. Can you share your pod spec?

Comment: @whites11 I added deployment file in the question description

Comment: Is the /healthz endpoint valid? You claimed that your app has everything exposed under /v1

Comment: @whites11 the error occurs with `/` endpoint, if you try `/healthz` the message change to this, so is not the problem here.

Ingress controller documentation quote some thing about `/` endpoint in here: https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/default-backend/

Comment: @btd1337 any progrres on the issue?